# Clang fails with template static constexpr variable member?

Tags: c++, c++17, clang++

I'am trying to compile a C++17 code base using clang, but clang crashes with a segmentation fault. If I use this simple construct, clang still crash on all version that supports c++17. I was wondering if there were anything wrong with the declaration of `test::asame`? it look likes these template static constexpr variable are the cause of clang crashes:

```
#include<type_traits>
using namespace std;
struct A{};
struct B{};
template<class U>
struct test{
  template<class T>
  static constexpr bool asame =is_same_v<T,U> ;
  using type =  conditional_t< asame<A> ,B ,A>;
  static constexpr bool asameA =test<U>::asame<A> ;
  };
static_assert(test<A>::asameA); //=> static expression is not an integral constant expression
static_assert(test<B>::asameA); //=> static expression is not an integral constant expression
static_assert(is_same_v<A,typename test<A>::type>); //=> ok, but
static_assert(is_same_v<B,typename test<A>::type>); //=> also ok! -> then clang crash in real code base
```

Comment: A compiler crash is always a bug of compiler, even if code is incorrect. which seems not be the case here.

Comment: Clang has also issue in C++14 mode [Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/Rc4mh1).

Comment: I agree with Jarod - please file a bug at bugs.llvm.org

Comment: @MarshallClow I have asked to have an account on llvm bugzilla. I am waiting for an answer.